# Hibernate SQLQuery with transient properties

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I need to make an hibernate SQLQuery with db2 and this query is returning me some fields which are calculated and have no relation with any columns in database.

The goal is setting the values of these sum() calculations from SQLQuery on three new transient fields in a Java Object which already existed.

The SQLQuery uses the syntax:

```
SELECT id as {entityObject.id},
           name as {entityObject.name},
           order as {entityObject.order},
           SUM(CASE
           WHEN pv.value_id = 1 
            AND pv.value=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS {entityObject.someCount}
```

The problem is that Hibernate complains and says to need a column for someCount. It seems not to help declaring the java field as ***transient*** or even using the ***@Transient*** annotation from javax.persistence at the same time.

If I only declare in the hbm.xml mapping file:

```
<property name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="someColumn" />
<!-- Some more fields here -->

<!-- THE IMPORTANT ONE -->
<property name="someCount" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

Java Object:

```
public class EntityObject implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1479579608940145961L;

private Integer id;
private String name;
private Integer order;

    // This is the one giving me hell. I've tried with @Transient also
private transient Integer someCount;

public Category() {
}

public Category(final String name, final Integer order) {
    this.name = name;
    this.order = order;
}

public Integer getOrder() {
    return this.order;
}

public void setOrder(final Integer order) {
    this.order = order;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public Integer getSomeCount() {
    return someCount;
}

public void setSomeCount(final Integer count) {
    this.someCount = count;
}


}
```

It asks me for a column, and I have tried inserting a fake column and it does not work. The thing is that I want these 'count' fields only to be set from the SQLQuery and to be empty and null when coming from a regular Hibernate Query.

I have looked at the docs and googled, and it seems that you can declare a field transient by only not declaring it at the hibernate mapping file, but then it does not set it on the object with the "as {entityObject.someCount}" even when I have getters/setters declared.

Help please.
Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't 'see' transient fields.  You will have to do the aggregation queries and put the results in the fields in your code after the query returns.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. 
Secondly, ¿how do I get these values then if I can't map them directly from the SQLQuery to the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Create a POJO:

```
public class SumValue{
   private BigInteger myId; 
   private String myName;
   private BigInteger myOrder;
   private BigInteger mySum;
   ....
   getters and setters here
   ....
}
```

2 Minor changes in your query

```
SELECT id as "myId",
       name as "myName",
       order as "myOrder",
       SUM(CASE
       WHEN pv.value_id = 1 
        AND pv.value=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "mySum"
```

3 Execute native sql

```
     List<SumValue> jobStateViewList = (List<SumValue>)getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                                   .createSQLQuery(yourQuery)
                                   .setResultTransformer(
                                        new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(SumValue.class)
                                   ).list();
```

Comment: Mmmmmh, I'm afraid I didn't explain well myself. I'm editing the main question. But in advance I explain to you...

There is an only Java object with three aggregate fields like the one I posted, and also as well another fields mapped as usual.

Tell me if I'm wrong, but your solution only sets the value on a POJO containing only one value. I want all the retrieved values in the same object.

I'm clarifying this just now by editing the initial post. Sorry about this.

Comment: I don't see any Java object in your post. From your sql query I understand that you need to transform sum value returned by sql into object. So, once again show me please the object you want to populate with data from sql query.

Comment: I think now is complete. Sorry about the inconveniences.

Comment: I edited my post. I also have one question. Did you map EntityObject as Hibernate entity?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm at some other taks with higher priority right now. I'm coming back to this later.

Comment: For some reasons, it tells me it can't find the setter for ID (like this, in capitals). I have added it with no changes in the result.

Comment: In your example, I see you haven't id setter.

Comment: Yes, but I added later. It is public. I can't understand why is not found. Looking at the og I verified that the query goes fine, but the problem arises when passing the values to the object's fields.

Comment: To help you I need to see your edited sql and Hibernate logs. Did you leave your POJO the same? Aliases(names) in your sql must be equal to POJO fields(its names).

Comment: Finally I did it! I thought the quotes were not necessary and would cause a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The only option available that might do all this directly from the Database without having to issue additional queries is a Hibernate Formula property:

http://wiki.jrapid.com/w/Formula_(attribute_of_property)

```
<property name="someCount" formula="select count(*) from some_table where table_key = ?"/>
```

The ? placeholder will be populated automatically with the ID of the current instance.

Comment: Thanks, I thought on this but I need to do it in the sql query for efficiency as well as for company rules related to style and so on.