# Map aggregate column from SQL query to transient property

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Is there a way using Hibernate to make a SQL query that returns all the properties of an entity and an additional aggregated column and have the result to be mapped through an Entity mapping and also map the aggregated column to a transient property of the same entity class?

SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, slc( ?, ?, p.latitude, p.longitude)*1000 as distance from xxx as up, xxx as p 
WHERE (up.user_id IN (
    select followee_id from user_followers WHERE owner_id = ?) OR up.user_id = ?) 
    AND up.place_id = p.id order by distance desc
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xxx")
@Spatial(name = "place")
public class Place extends BasicEntity {

/**
 * The id of the place in the third party information service.
 */
@Column(name = "external_id", unique = true)
private String externalId;

/**
 * The place's name.
 */
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

/**
 * The place latitude.
 */
@Latitude(of = "place")
private Double latitude;

/**
 * The place longitude.
 */
@Longitude(of = "place")
private Double longitude;

... some other attributes.

/**
 * The distance between the place and the user's location.
 */
@Transient
private double distance;

... setters and getters
}
```

Hibernate Query:

```
Query query = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(Place.class)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate SQLQuery with transient properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139488/hibernate-sqlquery-with-transient-properties)